# Use dir /s but ignore specific subdirs

Tags: cmd

I have a project on github that's used primarily by people who don't know much about computers.  It's pretty well documented, but the alignment of the stars plays a large role in whether it will work for them, so when it doesn't, they contact me on Discord for troubleshooting.

One thing that's helpful to me is a list of all the files they have in the project.  To do this, I'd use `dir /s /b > filelist.txt`.  However, as one directory is a node.js project, there's a `node_modules` subdirectory with thousands of files that won't help in troubleshooting.

Is there a good way to ignore specific subdirectories?  `node_modules` is not the only one I'd ignore.

One method would be to pipe the `dir` results into `findstr` and use a negative regex, but this could be very slow since it's sifting through every file in the `node_modules` and including none of them.

Comment: With `dir /b/s` you can't avoid diving into (unwanted) subdirs. I'd use a batch and recursively call a subroutine which immediately returns hitting an unwanted folder.

Comment: __DIR__ does not offer an exclude option as otherwise it would be explained by the help output on running `dir /?` in a command prompt window. __XCOPY__ and __ROBOCOPY__ have exclude options and have both option `/L` to just __list__ the files which would be copied instead of really copying them. I recommend usage of __ROBOCOPY__ for this task. Get help on this command by running in a command prompt window `robocopy /?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a directory that should not appear in the output, it can be taken out. See `FIND /?` for more information about `/V`.

```
DIR /S /B | FIND /V "\node_modules\"

DIR /S /B | FIND /V "\node_modules\" >filelist.txt
```